# Http post return data with invalid characters in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Http post return data with invalid characters

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt';

$params = array('receipt-data' => 'receipt data');

$params = json_encode($params);
```

my code is

```
 $client = new Client();
 $client->setUri($url);
 $client->setMethod('POST');
 $client->setRawBody($params);
 $client->setHeaders(array(
   'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
 ));
 $client->setAdapter(new Curl());
 $response = $client->send();

 $res      = $response->getContent();
```

my out put is this

����

if any one know about this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode JSON response from the body like this:

`var_dump(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));`

Then you will get an array with proper response :)

e.g.:

`array(1) { ["status"]=> int(21002) }`